# CORS issue in API gateway lamba-proxy integration

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm currently on a serverless application and my serverless.yml looks like

```
functions:
  app:
    handler: server.run
    events:
     - http:
          path: /api/{any+}
          method: ANY 

     - http:
          path: /secure/api/{any+}
          method: ANY 
          cors :
            origins
              - domain-url-1
              - domain-url-2
```

As you can see above one is a secured route and that requires authorization whereas the non-secure route doesn't require any authorization headers to be passed. Since lambda-proxy doesn't take api gateway response I'm attaching the response headers on my app.js as below and for every route I'm sending the status and status codes separately in res objects.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");
  // res.headersSent("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, accesstoken");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

But my api gateway works fine for non-secure routes while for secure routes I'm getting a CORS issue with

```
** Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
polyfills.ff5fcb5319b1dc651f7b.js:1 GET https://8nv8r4ph65.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/secure/api/v1/legal/notification/list?rowsPerPage=15 net::ERR_FAILED **
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your origin header does not match specified domains in ApiGateway. For fast verification remove specified domains in serverless.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your secured routes are using one of the methods to pass authentication status that the browser detects as being a request with credentials. Some of the ways a browser marks a request as credentialed is if the request sends back a cookie or if the request includes the `Authorization` header.

Credentialed requests have an additional rule regarding CORS. The origin `*` is illegal for credentialed requests. Browser manufacturers instead want server admin/backend developers to tell the browser exactly what domain name is valid for the CORS request.

In addition to the rule above, list of domain names are also illegal for credentialed requests. A request with credentials can **only accept one domain** for CORS.

You can of course hardcode the domain name of your frontend in your server code. But this gets annoying and is not flexible in case you need to serve multiple domains.

The **correct** working solution for this scenario (indeed, the way CORS was intended to be used) is to check the `Origin` header in the request.

The laziest way to make it work is to simply copy the `Origin` header to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get("Origin"));
```

This will allow anyone in the world from any website to access your data. This is perfectly fine if you are OK with this and only care about using authentication to protect your data instead of also using the CORS mechanism.

If you are using the `cors` middleware you it will do this for you if you pass `true` as origin:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

The way CORS is intended to be used is to check the `Origin` against a list of approved domains:

```
const approvedDomains = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://my.application.com",
    "http://my.application.com"   // etc..
]

function checkDomains(origin) {
    return approvedDomains.filter(domain => domain === origin)[0];
}

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", checkDomains(req.get("Origin")));
```

Again, the `cors` middleware makes this simple allowing you to pass an array of approved domain names and it will do the above logic for you:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: approvedDomains });
```